# Passing a block of code from Java to a Scala object

Tags: java, scala

I have a generic utility in `scala` to Retry a certain piece of code logic `n` number of times.

**RetryCode.scala**

```
object RetryCode {
    def retry[T](timesRetry: Int)(block: => T): T = {
        def doBlock() = block
        breakable {
            for (i <- 0 until timesRetry) {
                try {
                    ...
                    doBlock()
                } catch {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Unit in `Scala`:

```
class RetryCodeTest {
    test("success on 1st retry") {
        var i = 0
        val result = retry(5) {
          i = i + 1
          i
        }
        assert(result==1)
    }
}
```

I'd like to extend this functionality to a `Java` program

```
private void myMethod(int x) {
    try {
        // Code block to Retry 10 times
        ...
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How do I send a block of `Java 7` code to my `RetryCode` object in `Scala`?

Comment: create instance of Java class in the Scala class? call `myMethod` within the loop?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option as the Scala object is used frequently else where in Scala code base.

Comment: You don't; you do something with a lambda or an interface.

Comment: Lambda is not an option as it's Java 7 and not Java 8.

Comment: I'd overload the `retry()` method in Scala with one that takes a Java `Callable`, and passes it to your real retry method. Then in your Java you could create an anonymous `Callable` (or a lamda expression in Java 8). Something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `retry` which Java sees is `<T> T retry(int timesRetry, scala.Function0<T> block)`. So you need to instantiate a `Function0`, but extending it directly in Java won't work; instead you want

```
RetryCode.retry(10, new scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer apply() { return something; }
});
```

(At least if I remember correctly and the static method is generated on `RetryCode`).

Note that in general you can't just assume a Scala API will be reasonably callable from Java; you may need to write a wrapper for it (in Scala).

Comment: Unsure about this as things get quickly complicated with multiple arguments but +1 for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my `Java 7` program in `Scala`.